# How to dynamically set Grafana data source HTTP header based on the chosen value from a variable in dashboard?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-variable

I'm working with Cortex multi-tenancy where both write and read paths require `X-Scope-OrgID` HTTP header in the request.

The write path is working fine. But I can't figure out how to pass the chosen tenant name in my dashboard to the Cortex data source as `X-Scope-OrgID` HTTP header.

My current Grafana data sources look like this:

```
apiVersion: 1
datasources:
  - name: Prometheus
    type: prometheus
    url: "http://prom-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus.observability:9090"
  - name: Cortex
    type: prometheus
    url: "http://cortex-query-frontend-headless.cortex:8080/prometheus"
    isDefault: true
    jsonData:
      httpHeaderName1: 'X-Scope-OrgID'
    secureJsonData:
      httpHeaderValue1: 'cust-3b74e7dd-808d-default'
```

As you can see, I just hard coded the `X-Scope-OrgID` HTTP header value to a static tenant name (`cust-3b74e7dd-808d-default`). This works fine and the dashboard is able to load and display metrics from that specific hard coded tenant just fine.

And it looks like this:

[image]

Note:

The tenant names came from Prometheus data source

Question:

How do I pass the variable dropdown value to the Cortex data source as `X-Scope-OrgID` HTTP header? For example, when I choose `cust-test-1234` tenant, the request to Cortex should has `X-Scope-OrgID` HTTP header set to `cust-test-1234` as well.

References:

- https://cortexmetrics.io/docs/guides/auth/
- https://cortexmetrics.io/docs/guides/limitations/#tenant-id-naming

My dashboard in JSON:

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": {
          "type": "grafana",
          "uid": "-- Grafana --"
        },
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "target": {
          "limit": 100,
          "matchAny": false,
          "tags": [],
          "type": "dashboard"
        },
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editable": true,
  "fiscalYearStartMonth": 0,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": 2,
  "links": [],
  "liveNow": false,
  "panels": [
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "P6693426190CB2316"
      },
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "color": {
            "mode": "palette-classic"
          },
          "custom": {
            "axisCenteredZero": false,
            "axisColorMode": "text",
            "axisLabel": "",
            "axisPlacement": "auto",
            "barAlignment": 0,
            "drawStyle": "line",
            "fillOpacity": 0,
            "gradientMode": "none",
            "hideFrom": {
              "legend": false,
              "tooltip": false,
              "viz": false
            },
            "lineInterpolation": "linear",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "pointSize": 5,
            "scaleDistribution": {
              "type": "linear"
            },
            "showPoints": "auto",
            "spanNulls": false,
            "stacking": {
              "group": "A",
              "mode": "none"
            },
            "thresholdsStyle": {
              "mode": "off"
            }
          },
          "mappings": [],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "green",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "red",
                "value": 80
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 9,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 7,
        "y": 0
      },
      "id": 2,
      "options": {
        "legend": {
          "calcs": [],
          "displayMode": "list",
          "placement": "bottom",
          "showLegend": true
        },
        "tooltip": {
          "mode": "single",
          "sort": "none"
        }
      },
      "targets": [
        {
          "datasource": {
            "type": "prometheus",
            "uid": "P6693426190CB2316"
          },
          "editorMode": "code",
          "expr": "sum by (id) (dummy_foo)",
          "legendFormat": "__auto",
          "range": true,
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Foo",
      "type": "timeseries"
    }
  ],
  "schemaVersion": 37,
  "style": "dark",
  "tags": [],
  "templating": {
    "list": [
      {
        "current": {
          "selected": true,
          "text": "cust-15276cac-808d-default",
          "value": "cust-15276cac-808d-default"
        },
        "datasource": {
          "type": "prometheus",
          "uid": "PBFA97CFB590B2093"
        },
        "definition": "label_values(namespace)",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": false,
        "multi": false,
        "name": "tenant",
        "options": [],
        "query": {
          "query": "label_values(namespace)",
          "refId": "StandardVariableQuery"
        },
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "cust-.*",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "type": "query"
      }
    ]
  },
  "time": {
    "from": "now-5m",
    "to": "now"
  },
  "timepicker": {},
  "timezone": "",
  "title": "My dashboard",
  "uid": "nqdvuvK4z",
  "version": 1,
  "weekStart": ""
}
```